LinkedIn API issues
I am trying got use LinkedIn API but the only route that works for me is /v2/me.
When querying /v2/activities is returning an error

404 - RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND - No virtual resource found

    import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';

    interface PersonResult {
      id: string;
      firstName: string;
      lastName: string;
      profilePicture?: {
        displayImage: string;
      };
      publicIdentifier: string;
    }

    export class LinkedInClient {
      private axiosInstance: AxiosInstance;

      constructor(accessToken: string, baseUrl: string = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2') {
        this.axiosInstance = axios.create({
          baseURL: baseUrl,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'X-Restli-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
          },
        });
      }

      private async apiCall<T>(endpoint: string, params: Record<string, string>): Promise<T | null> {
        try {
          const response = await this.axiosInstance.get(endpoint, { params });

          return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
          
          // If error is AxiosError
          if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
            console.error(`LiknedIn API [${endpoint}] failed with error: ${error.response?.data.status} - ${error.response?.data.code} - ${error.response?.data.message}`);
          } else {
            console.error(error);
          }

          return null;
        }
      }

      async getProfile(): Promise<PersonResult | null> {
        return this.apiCall<PersonResult>('/me', {
          projection: '(id,firstName,lastName,profilePicture(displayImage~:playableStreams),publicIdentifier)',
        });
      }

      async getActivities(): Promise<any | null> {
        return this.apiCall<any>('/activities', {});
      }

    }

